# Chef recipe for a single node cassandra on Windows

Tags: automation, scripting, chef-infra

I need help to start writing Chef recipe for a single node cassandra on windows.
Appreciate if someone can guide me in this effort, I am relatively new to chef.

Thanks,
MT

Answer (score 0):

join https://learn.chef.io to get through automation.
Join in slack community so that more people can help you on that.
https://community-slack.chef.io/